# How can I keep the same button size after it changes content?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that has some text inside it, when clicked, a loading spinner with class `ellipsisLoader`
displays, the problem is that the spinner takes less space than the text, so the button gets smaller horizontally.
I want the loading spinner to take as much space as the text does so the button doesn't resize when loading.

I have tried setting a `min-width` in the css file, however it becomes not as responsive when the screen is resized.

**JS file:**

```
            <div className="checkout">
              <br />
              <button disabled={this.state.disableSubmit} style={{ padding: "0% 10%" }} className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.submit}>
                {!this.state.disableSubmit ? this.props.t('Update information')
              :
                (<div class="ellipsisLoader"> <div class="bounce1"></div> <div class="bounce2"></div> <div class="bounce3"></div> </div>)}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**CSS File:**

```
.checkout {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.checkout button {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  background-color: #4628C7;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.checkout form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e6ebf1;
}

.checkout button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #5033ca;
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: don't remove the text, make it hidden and put the loader above

Comment: "don't remove the text, make it hidden and put the loader above." Be careful how you do this, it can cause accessibility issues. iirc Screen Readers will read the text unless it is `visibility: hidden`.